# SQL Server Job - how to generate script for Alert System Settings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-agent, sql-server-job

In our SQL Server 2008 Agent properties dialog box we have set an Alert System settings as shown below. But when we try to generate a script for that we get the following message - hence unable to generate a T-SQL script. Is there a T-SQL script or stored procedure to create such setting:

[image]

**UPDATE**
Please note that this is not to create an alert. Instead, it's an step [shown here](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/desiree/how-to-set-up-database-mail-for-sql-server-job-failures/) to set the System Alert property of the SQL Server Agent when configuring a Database Mail (also shown in the above link)

Comment: I think you made the changes earlier and now you are trying to script them out, You will need to revert the changes and save it and come out of it, open the properties section again make the changes and before you save them then click on `Script` and it will generate the script for you.

Comment: @M.Ali Please see my comments below.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Given your update, I agree with @M.Ali. Either undo your change and re-do it but hit the Script button before you hit "OK" in the dialog or implement the change on a system where it hasn't been implemented yet and do the same (i.e. hit Script before OK).